# bash script read all the files in directory

Tags: linux, bash

How do I loop through a directory? I know there is `for f in /var/files;do echo $f;done;` The problem with that is it will spit out all the files inside the directory all at once. I want to go one by one and be able to do something with the $f variable. I think the while loop would be best suited for that but I cannot figure out how to actually write the while loop.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The `for` loop is exactly right, but you are looping over a single item, the literal directory name `/var/files`. Your problem description is incorrect; the program you posted will simply echo `/var/files`. I suspect you may want `for f in /var/files/*`. Take care to use double quotes around `"$f"` everywhere.

Answer (score 86):

A simple loop should be working:

```
for file in /var/*
do
    #whatever you need with "$file"
done
```

See [bash filename expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion)

Comment: @Mu_Qiao - I have two commands in the shell script after the do. The first is to echo $file and then echo "hi". I have 10 files in the directory. I'm getting the ten filenames and then the hi rather than 1,hi,2,hi,3,hi...etc

Comment: O.K. got it. Maybe it was because I was using quotes around my directory name.

Comment: @mike yes quotes prevent filename expansions

Comment: @Mu_Qiao - So what do you do if there is a space in the filename?

Comment: @mike it's ok, just use double quotes around $file

Answer (score 12):

To write it with a while loop you can do:

```
ls -f /var | while read -r file; do cmd $file; done
```

The primary disadvantage of this is that cmd is run in
a subshell, which causes some difficulty if you are trying
to set variables.  The main advantages are that the shell
does not need to load all of the filenames into memory, and
there is no globbing.  When you have a lot of files in
the directory, those advantages are important (that's
why I use -f on ls; in a large directory ls itself can
take several tens of seconds to run and -f speeds that
up appreciably.  In such cases 'for file in /var/*'
will likely fail with a glob error.)

Comment: Nice solution.  It's the only one that works with a very full directory and a complex cmd.

Comment: But includes `.` and `..`

Answer (score 7):

You can go without the loop:

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -exec /your/first/command \{\} \; -exec /your/second/command \{\} \;
```

HTH

Comment: why do you escape \{\}?