# How to store and iterate the list of files in a directory(each file need to pass as a input for java module)

Tags: shell, iteration

i am new to the shell script . i have a requirement that i need to pass a input file (one at a time)for the java program.i have a multiple inputfiles in the directory.how to store and iterate the input files.any code snippet for this is helpful .thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bash script read all the files in directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290758/bash-script-read-all-the-files-in-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something on the below lines. 
Create array of files

```
files=$(ls <directory name with complete path which contains all the files>)
e.g: files=$(ls /tmp/siva/)
```

Access items from an array:

```
for i in "${files[@]}";
do;
java <your classname> $i;
done;
```

[Reference](http://www.tecmint.com/working-with-arrays-in-linux-shell-scripting/)

Let me know if you need further help

Comment: Your solution is not scalable since you have manually input the filenames into the array `files`.

Comment: well the OP did not specify means of entering input files..so i took the simplest approach..but i am quite sure it can be modified

Comment: input files are available in a directory.the count of  files may be in hundreds .the above mentioned approach is feasible? is there any other solution?

Comment: Please check now the files array command in the post and that should do the trick for you